# using spring.application.json for application.properties file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to use the command `-Dspring.application.json='{"foo":{"bar":"spam"}}'` from the spring docs but while seeing it in IntelliJ's run command it always fails with `Could not resolve placeholder`

I have tried to use System Variable and the Java Ops variable with no success.

what i have code wise:
Application.properties:

```
testing=${foo.bar}
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Value("${testing:}")
    private String input;

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchDetails set() {
        System.out.println("input: " + input);
        return new BatchDetails("Test", "Test2");
    }
}
```

IntelliJ VM Options:
`-Dspring.application.json='{"foo":{"bar":"spam"}}'`

IntelliJ Environment variables:
`SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON = '{"foo":{"bar":"spam"}}'`

on startup of the application i get the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'foo.bar' in string value "${foo.bar}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:178) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:195) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:87) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:60) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:531) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:132) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:84) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getPropertyAsRawString(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver$1.resolvePlaceholder(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:207) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:153) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:178) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:172) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:808) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1027) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 80 common frames omitted
```

am i just putting the configuration in the wrong place for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "expand" Spring's `application.properties` like that. Both all the values from there and the System-level `spring.application.json` are loaded into your `Environment` variable and you can access `foo.bar` from there.

So, basically..

Spring takes `testing` from your `application.properties` expecting a **fully-formed** value, then it takes the JSON from your System variable, expecting a **fully-formed** value and merges them into `Environment`.

Now you can do

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

env.getProperty("testing");
env.getProperty("foo.bar");

//OR
@Value(${"foo.bar"})
private String valueFromFooBar
```

Comment: so i tried the `@Value` and it still didn't like it. i am really trying to simulate PCF's VCAP_SERVICES locally so i don't want to use Environment. I will just use the -Dfull.name.of.service=value locally.

Answer (score 0):

I try to add `-Dspring.application.json='{"foo":{"bar":"spam"}}'` to my test,but it doesn't parse correctly.
you can try `--spring.application.json={\"foo\":\"bar\"}` instead,it works well;

actually,when spring is running, it parser the configure options into the enviroment,just like the picture .firstly ,parser the commandarguements into `PropertySource name='commandLineArgs'`,then,after parsered by `SpringApplicationJsonEnvironmentPostProcessor`,split the value in `spring.application.json`into a lonely PropertySource name `spring.application.json`.

[parsered bySpringApplicationJsonEnvironmentPostProcessor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3aE1.png)